# Simulate directory File object

Tags: javascript, html, file, dom, directory

In JavaScript, how do I create a `File` (or `Blob`) object that simulates a directory?

On Chrome 43, when I log an image file dragged into an upload form, I get this:

```
lastModified: 1426770718000
lastModifiedDate: Thu Mar 19 2015 06:11:58 GMT-0700 (PDT)
name: "Cornered.jpg"
size: 261343
type: "image/jpeg"
webkitRelativePath: ""
```

When I log a directory, I get this:

```
lastModified: 1426770841000
lastModifiedDate: Thu Mar 19 2015 06:14:01 GMT-0700 (PDT)
name: "contest"
size: 476
type: ""
webkitRelativePath: ""
```

The only differences seem to be the lack of extension and the empty `type`.

[This answer](http://ttp://stackoverflow.com/a/8857445/1468130) describes how to *detect* a directory. I want to simulate a directory so I can write a unit test for the following function:

```
var isDirectory = function (blob, callback) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.addEventListener('load', function () {
        callback(false);
    });
    reader.addEventListener('error', function () {
        callback(true);
    });
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
};
```

I've tried just passing it a `new Blob([])`, as that also has a `type` of empty string, but `callback` was still invoked with `false`.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is unit test that function, you could simply mock JavaScript's `FileReader`:

```
    describe('isDirectory', function () {
        var OriginalFileReader,
            MockFileReader = function () {
                this.callbacks = {};
                mockFileReaderInstance = this;
            },
            mockFileReaderInstance;

        MockFileReader.prototype = {
            addEventListener: function (event, callback) {
                this.callbacks[event] = callback;
            },
            readAsArrayBuffer: angular.noop
        };

        beforeEach(function () {
            OriginalFileReader = window.FileReader;
            window.FileReader = MockFileReader;
        });
        afterEach(function () {
            window.FileReader = OriginalFileReader;
        });

        it('should indicate false when object is not a directory', function () {
            var spy = jasmine.createSpy('spy');

            fileUtilities.isDirectory({}, spy);
            mockFileReaderInstance.callbacks.load();

            expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(false);
        });

        it('should indicate true when object is a directory', function () {
            var spy = jasmine.createSpy('spy');

            fileUtilities.isDirectory({}, spy);
            mockFileReaderInstance.callbacks.error();

            expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(true);
        });
    });
```

Granted, this makes certain assumptions about the inner workings of the `FileReader` itself, but ostensibly it's already been tested by browser manufacturers and you can assume it works as advertized.